When does spring-web throw a BindException?
I have two exception handlers in my code: one for BindException and another for MethodArgumentNotValidException. In my tests, I'm unable to find a way to trigger the Spring framework to throw a BindException.
Examples I've found online, such as setting validation on endpoint parameters, no longer throw a BindException but instead the MethodArgumentNotValidException.
I've also noticed that exception handlers have now removed handling BindException since 6.2, leading me to question if it ever needs handling in its raw form.
I have found that DefaultServerRequest and WebRequestDataBinder do throw a BindException, but it's unclear to me how I can trigger this in my test setup.
